# Generating Cartesian points over 2d domain in Matlab or Python

Tags: python, matlab

kindly suggest me how to generate the points over 2d domains.
suppose, we have square, circle, star-shaped domain, random sketched domain,etc
then how can we get the points over the entire interior domain as well as on the boundary of the domain.

in python or Matlab coding.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems/errors have you incountered?

Comment: generating points over simple geometry in 1d, 2d is fine for me but the complex shaped geometry is have complex boundaries as well as interior domain which seems complex coding for me. Thanks||

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def shape(x_left,x_right,num_x,num_y,top_func,bottom_func):
    x = np.linspace(x_left,x_right,num_x)
    y_top = top_func(x)
    y_bottom = bottom_func(x)
    y = np.linspace(y_bottom,y_top,num_y)
    return np.c_[np.tile(x,num_y),np.ravel(y)]

def plot_points(points):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_aspect('equal',adjustable='box')
    plt.scatter(points[:,0],points[:,1])
    plt.show()

circle_top = lambda x: np.sqrt(1-x**2)
circle_bottom = lambda x: -np.sqrt(1-x**2)
circle_points = shape(-1,1,20,20,circle_top,circle_bottom)
plot_points(circle_points)


square_top = lambda x: 1*np.ones(x.shape)
square_bottom = lambda x: -1*np.ones(x.shape)
square_points = shape(-1,1,20,20,square_top,square_bottom)
plot_points(square_points)
```

[image: Circle]
[image: Square]

Comment: @SKS You can't do a star shape with this code since it crosses some vertical lines through the shape in more than two places e.g. the middle of the top-left arm and bottom-left arm of the star = 4 crossovers. If you have a generic list of edge points for a shape, you can interpolate with splines, and like this code, process things line by line, counting how many crossovers the shape has. On a given line, you can assume less than the minimum crossover point is outside the shape, and as you go towards the maximum crossover point on the line you toggle between being inside vs out of the shape.

Comment: @SKS Perhaps another thought is to come up with a function that intersects your shape outline as a contour and has a non-zero gradient on all points on that contour. The interior of the shape could be identified as all points on the function either less than or greater than the contour value depending on how you define it. This probably better extends to higher dimensions. It might be helpful if the shape specification also includes an explicit interior point as an input. You could then have f(x,y)=0 at your shape edge points and set f(x,y)=1 at your interior point and construct the function.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am working on it.  Sir, can we perform this operation over arbitrary shaped domain which equation is unknown.

Comment: Your suggestion for picking the interior point based on f(x,y) helps me in simple geometry.  Now, I am facing a problem in parametric equation, where this condition is not helping me to choose the interior points.  I have successfully identify the boundary points of equation, whose parametric form is,  r = 1.5 +0.14*sin(4*theta) + 0.12*cos(6*theta) + 0.09*cos(5*theta), and  x = 0.02 + r*cos(theta),    y = r*sin(theta)      Kindly, suggest me some idea for generating the interior points of such closed contour.